# Why can't I apply a function to create a new column with mutate() using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame, let's call it " df".

I'm trying to create a column, let's call it "result", summing four other columns.

Using dplyr, I can do it with the following code:

```
mutate(df, result=col1+col2+col3+col4)
```

However, when I try the following:

```
mutate(df, result=sum(col1, col2, col3, col4))
```

It's not working. Why is it occurring?

Comment: Those do two different things, by design. Forget dplyr, define some vectors and compare `col1 + col2` to `sum(col1,col2)`. They do different things.

Comment: Try `sum(df$col1,df$col2)` and you will see it is a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: `sum()` always collapses down to a single value and `mutate()` runs by passing in entire columns at a time to the function. The `+` operator is vectorized and is preferred in this case.

Comment: You're right. They're completely different.

Comment: If you want to sum all the columns but don't like typing `+`, there's ```Reduce(`+`,list(col1,col2,col3,col4))```. I bet there's a fancy `dplyr` shorthand for that `list`...

Comment: or even `df$result <- rowSums(df[c("col1","col2","col3","col4")])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out `+` and `sum()` differ in behaviour. Consider:

```
> sum(1:10,1:10)
[1] 110
> `+`(1:10,1:10)
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

#### If you really want to `sum()` the variables along each row you want **`rowwise()`**:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(w = letters[1:3], x=1:3, y = x^2, z = y - x)

#     Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#     
#       w x y z
#     1 a 1 1 0
#     2 b 2 4 2
#     3 c 3 9 6


df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(result = sum(x, y, z))

#   Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#   Groups: <by row>
#     
#     w x y z result
#   1 a 1 1 0      2
#   2 b 2 4 2      8
#   3 c 3 9 6     18
```

Compare this to:

```
df %>% mutate(result = x + y + z)
#   Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#   
#     w x y z result
#   1 a 1 1 0      2
#   2 b 2 4 2      8
#   3 c 3 9 6     18
df %>% mutate(result = sum(x, y, z))  # sums over all of x, y and z and recycles the result!
#   Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#   
#     w x y z result
#   1 a 1 1 0     28
#   2 b 2 4 2     28
#   3 c 3 9 6     28
```